# how to make talkback read texts from a screen whenever it changes its content and without having to make gestures

Tags: kotlin

I have a screen like instagram stories and I want talkback to read the texts on it whenever I change screens

I tried to call a contentDescription getting the position of the first and last whenever I went to the next stories but it only reads once and when I click on the button to go to the next one it doesn't read anymore